# getVersionsByEntryId is deprecated. Can't find the new method?

Tags: elementquery

We are using `getVersionsByEntryId` in our XML sitemap to return the number of times an entry has been saved, then comparing that with todays date and the date the entry was created to determine the `changefreq` over that time:

```
{% set revisions = craft.app.entryRevisions.getVersionsByEntryId(element.id)|default(1)|length %}
```

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-entryrevisions.html#public-methods) however, this is now deprecated:

> DEPRECATED
>
> Deprecated in 3.2. Use an entry query instead.

I can't seem to find anything in the docs for an entry query? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think this is what you need - https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#revisionof

Comment: Cheers Oli, that's exactly what I needed: `{% set revisions = craft.entries.revisionOf(element.id).all|default(1) %}`. Please post that as an answer and I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `revisionOf` parameter ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#revisionof)).

```twig
{% set revisions = craft.entries.revisionOf(element.id).all|default(1) %}
```

Comment: Thanks again Oli!